# How to append the multiple option value in a single column in my database

Tags: php

```
 <legend>Day And Time Available:</legend>  
<input type="checkbox" class="day" name="day[]" value="monday" onclick="show(this);"/>Monday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="day"  name="day[]" value="tuesday" onclick="show(this);"/>Tuesday<br/>
```

Monday

```
<label for="FromtimeMonday">From Time</label>
<select name="FromtimeMonday" id="FromtimeMonday">
<option value="Monday6Am">6Am</option>
<option value="Monday7Am">7Am</option>
<option value="Monday8Am">8Am</option>
</select>
<label for="TotimeMonday">To Time</label>
<select name="TotimeMonday" id="TotimeMonday">
<option value="Monday6Am">6Am</option>
<option value="Monday7Am">7Am</option>
<option value="Monday8Am">8Am</option>
</select>  
<p>Tuesday</p>
<label for="FromtimeTueday">From Time</label>
<select name="FromtimeTueday" id="FromtimeTueday">
<option value="Tueday6Am">6Am</option>
<option value="Tueday7Am">7Am</option>
<option value="Tueday8Am">8Am</option>
</select>
<label for="TotimeTueday">To Time</label>
<select name="TotimeTueday" id="TotimeTueday">
<option value="Tueday6Am">6Am</option>
<option value="Tueday7Am">7Am</option>
<option value="Tueday8Am">8Am</option>
</select>   
Here is my php code:


 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    include('manager/connection.php');
$time=',';
$d=$_POST['day'];
$day=implode(",",$d);
$FromtimeMonday=$_POST['FromtimeMonday'];
$TotimeMonday=$_POST['TotimeMonday'];
$FromtimeTueday=$_POST['FromtimeTueday'];
$TotimeTueday=$_POST['TotimeTueday'];
$time.= $FromtimeMonday;
$time.= $TotimeMonday.",";
$time.= $FromtimeTueday;
$time.= $TotimeTueday;
$sql=mysql_query("insert into timing (day,timing) values ('".$day."','".$time."')");
}
    }
    ?>
```

Here I am appending the values to time variable .I am creating the database with column name day,timing  how to bring the data to specific column.because I am creating db like this.more over It depends on the person day and time so for every one it may varry.how to make the db column proper for this.here the  form label day is array. if you see my db structure you can understand.Like wise if user selects monday,tuesday,thursday,wednesday.how to bring the data in timing column.if you have any better way to do this please kind me.

```
id   day             timing
7   monday,tuesday  ,Monday6AmTO6Am,Tueday6AmTO6Am
```

Comment: Now please check I have updated the php code .now you can understand my logic. what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Database columns shouldn't contain multiple values in a single column. This is called database normalization. If you don't normalize, you will suffer a lot of pain along the route.

Comment: Furthermore, if it works and you want to ask for a better solution, post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My suggestion is another database structure, one row for each user-day-to-from entry. So a table with the columns `userid`,`day`,`to` and `from` or something.

Normalize as @stt-lcu mentioned.

Comment: @llernestal Are you saying that normalization is wrong?

Comment: No @sasanka-panguluri a typo... I read to fast and typed to fast... fixed now ;)

Comment: is there is any problem multiple values in a single column? I will user explode to retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

The way you're storing times in the database is plain wrong. Considering using dates(timestamps) instead of string literals that say `Monday6AM` and stuff. And also consider normalizing your database.

`timestamp` in MYSQL has both date and time.

You'll achieve something like this:

```
id  Date(Timestamp)             other columns

8   01-01-2015 06:04:03.678     .....
```

Comment: ok .the way I have attached the string is correct?  see the variable time?. because I don't know what to do here. what value shall I need to give in my form

Comment: What I'm saying is, do not say monday6AM and stuff. Instead, allow the user to provide timestamps like 02-01-2015 01:02:07 in the form.

We have some javascript based date pickers already to ease your work.

Comment: Yes . my requirement is user picks any day in a week like monday,Tues,wed,thur,sat and sunda.for that what shall I do. if you see the form.you can understand my point. assume if I picks monday and tuesday for that I need to ask timing starttime and end time.onece data goes to server.I will display to userside.assume if you choose 7 days in a week I want to ask time for each day from time and to time

Comment: Do you mean picking monday from a given week, or any week?